# How do you combine two stats into one scoreboard objective?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I want to create a scoreboard objective for the amount of times a player falls 50 blocks, places a water bucket, and survives the fall. I only want the player to get a point if they manage to do all three of the items, in sequence. I can't figure out how to make an objective like this, I've only been able to create objectives with a single stat.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the 2 scoreboards set up, its easy to combine them:

Make a new objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add surivefall dummy surivefall
```

And then run this on a clock:

```
/execute @a[score_objective1_min=<yourvalue>,score_objective=<yourvalue>,score_objective2_min=<yourvalue>,score_objective2=<yourvalue>] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players add @p survivefall 1
```

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is make the objectives and give them different displays.
(Belowname, Sidebar or List)

PS: There is a plugin that does that. but i dont know the name, another mod took care of that plugin when we used it.

Comment: Telling someone he can look for a plugin isn't very helpful, I'm afraid.  Is there one that can do what he wants?  If so, which one is it, and how does he use it to solve his problem?